# What is an iOS 16-compatible way of turning a list of uniform type indicator strings (e.g., ["public.text", "public.image"]) into a list of UTType?

Tags: swift, ios16, uti, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, uttype

My app has a list of supported uniform type indicator (UTI) strings:

```
    public static let supportedUTIs = ["public.text", "public.image", "com.adobe.pdf", "public.comma-separated-values-text", "com.microsoft.word.doc", "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", "com.microsoft.excel.xls", "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet", "com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt", "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation", "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iWork.Numbers.numbers", "com.apple.keynote.key"]
```

While working on moving my app's minimum deployment target up to iOS 16, I noticed that the usage of `UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes:in:)` has changed to `UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes:)` when planning to use import mode for files. Whereas `documentTypes` accepted `[String]`, the new `forOpeningContentTypes` parameter requires `[UTType]`.

I need to keep my list of UTI strings in the app since it is being used elsewhere, but is there a nice way to programmatically convert this list into a new list of `UTType` that I can pass into my `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

I've tried some older solutions from the forums here, but they tend not to be compatible with the minimum deployment target of iOS 16 since anything that uses `kUTType` is deprecated. I've also seen several examples of small type checks (e.g., this file is an image, this is a video, etc.), but I'm not sure what to do with the more specific file extensions in my `supportedUTIs` list.

Any insight on how to make this list conversion from `String` to `UTType` in iOS 16 would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `import UniformTypeIdentifiers` and map your strings into `UTType` using its initializer:

```
let utTypes = supportedUTIs.compactMap(UTType.init)
```

Comment: This is the most beautiful solution I could've asked for. Can't believe it was that simple — thank you so much!